# Can I use a water based undercoat between solvent-based primer and top coat?

Tags: wood, paint

I've primed some new wood with Dulux aluminium wood primer which is solvent based. Probably overkill, but I wanted a very good seal. I plan to finish with two coats of Dulux eggshell, which is also solvent based.

My question is firstly whether I need an undercoat at all, and secondly whether this also needs to be solvent based.

I have some Dulux water based undercoat which needs using up. Can I use this between two solvent based layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not mix types of paint like that.

Most paint systems I have worked with are designed so that the successive coats work together. Rust Oleum etc

Comment: I thought is was OK to use latex over oil, but not the other way around?  Latex paint breathes, and oil products don't.  So if you put oil over latex, moisture/air permeating the latex gets trapped and causes the oil top coat to blister.

Comment: @Solar Mike:  Agreed.  A lot of engineering goes into making paint and they are a "systems" as you said.  One more consideration is the type of "solvent". I've seen horrible, blistering results when a "hot" paint was applied over other paint.  It dissolved it and made a HUGE mess. (Thankfully, it wasn't me doing it).  If that happens, you end up having to strip the entire piece.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an additional undercoat after the prime coat. I am not even sure why you are proposing it.

The manufacturer does not recommend it:

[image]

Comment: The manufacturer doesn't specify what the "appropriate paint system" comprises. Hence my asking.